# How to use the Airflow DockerOperator on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, airflow

I have tried to run the Apache Airflow DockerOperator from Windows, but received the error

```
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Expose the Docker Daemon on TCP
   [image: Docker Desktop]
2. If you are running airflow from docker, than the host will most probably be:

   ```
   host = 'host.docker.internal'
   ```

   Otherwise - probably

   ```
   host = 'localhost'
   ```
3. Add the following url in the docker_url parameter:

   ```py
   DockerOperator(
       # ...
       docker_url=f'tcp://{host}:2375'
       # ...
   )
   ```

Comment: Setting host to 'host.docker.internal' solved my issue, thanks a lot !!

Comment: Long live Stack Overflow! :D